# Ruby issue with Bundler::GemNotFound

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

I've a problem with every gem I try to use.

I am using an Ubuntu machine.

The error is

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:in `block in materialize': Could not find chunky_png-1.3.6 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

The error is not specific to that gem, because it happen with different gem as well. I think is a path problem.

I've already tried to reinstall ruby. Any help will be very appreciate.

My environment:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.10p492 (2016-04-01 revision 54464) [x86_64-linux]

$ bundle env
Bundler   1.12.5
Rubygems  2.6.6
Ruby      2.1.10p492 (2016-04-01 revision 54464) [x86_64-linux]
GEM_HOME  /usr/local/bundle
GEM_PATH  
Git       2.1.4

$ gem environment
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.1.10 (2016-04-01 patchlevel 492) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bundle
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bundle/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/bundle
     - /root/.gem/ruby/2.1.0
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-document"
     - "update" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/bundle/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
```

List of gems

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (default: 1.2.4)
bundler (1.12.5)
chunky_png (1.3.6)
compass (1.0.3)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
ffi (1.9.14)
io-console (default: 0.4.3)
json (default: 1.8.1)
minitest (default: 4.7.5)
multi_json (1.12.1)
psych (default: 2.0.5)
rake (default: 10.1.0)
rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
rb-inotify (0.9.7)
rdoc (default: 4.1.0)
rubygems-update (2.6.6)
sass (3.4.22)
test-unit (default: 2.1.10.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this to install the gems without `sudo`.  It seems on my machine there were two locations for the gems, and when I installed via sudo, it placed them in the wrong location.  Installing with `gem install compass` for instance placed it in the correct location.